# Angular Recursive HTTP Request results in infinite loop

Tags: angular, typescript, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I'm having a very hard time implementing a recursive HTTP request functionality in an Angular application using HttpClient.

I have an API that serves some data for me. The API puts the data into pages, meaning that the first response contains a URL to the next page and so on. (it's a search request to the public HAPI FHIR server)

I found this link online explaining how I can achieve this, but it does not work for me:
https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/rxjs-understanding-expand-a5f8b41a3602

This is what I got at the moment:

In my service class:

```
getFhirVitalSigns(patientId: string): Observable<any> {

    let url = this.vitalSignsUrl + "?subject:Patient=" + patientId;

    console.log("Starting process for getting all vital signs")

    return this.getPage(url).pipe(
      expand(({next}) => next ? this.getPage(next) : empty()),
      concatMap(({content}) => content)
    );
  }

  getPage(url:string): Observable<{
    content: any[];
    next: string | null;
  }> {
    return this.http.get(url).pipe(
      map((response:any) => ({
        content: response.entry,
        next: this.getNextPage(response)
      }))
    );
  }

  getNextPage(response: any): string | null {

    let url: string | null = null;

    for (let link of response.link){
      if (link.relation = "next"){
         url = link.url;
      }
    }

    console.log("Found new page: " + url);

    return url;

  }
```

And this is the code snippet where I call my service method:

```
this.vitalSignsService.getFhirVitalSigns(this.patientId!).subscribe(
  (test) => console.log(test)
);
```

The problem now is: the code ends in an infinite loop. It looks like that the code does not realize when there is no new page anymore.

Can someone help me?

This is how the pages look like:

```
{
    "resourceType": "Bundle",
    "id": "67ea2654-e1a6-4d21-b242-66c99024df64",
    "meta": {
        "lastUpdated": "2020-09-02T19:32:30.124+00:00"
    },
    "type": "searchset",
    "total": 30,
    "link": [
        {
            "relation": "self",
            "url": "http://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/Observation?_count=1&subject%3APatient=1457293"
        },
        {
            "relation": "next",
            "url": "http://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4?_getpages=67ea2654-e1a6-4d21-b242-66c99024df64&_getpagesoffset=1&_count=1&_pretty=true&_bundletype=searchset"
        }
    ],
    "entry": [
        {
            "fullUrl": "http://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/Observation/1457319",
            "resource": {
                // actual data of first data item
            }
    ]
}
```

Comment: just what do you want to achieve? do you want to download just one page? or maybe all of them and there is a lot of them, while your code still trying to get them all

Comment: I want to get the data from all pages. There is just 2 pages for my sample, but there can be any kind of page count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to replace

```
if (link.relation = "next"){
```

with

```
if (link.relation == "next"){
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much!! This solved it. This happens so many times to me that I type = instead of == during a logical statement .... I spent so many hours yesterday only because of this minor mistake :(((

Comment: #allThe...SmallThings